# Convert from Norand PL\N formatting to plain text

Tags: c#, intermec

Does anyone have any idea how to convert from Norand (now intermec's) proprietary format PL\N to plaintext?  We have an application that was written before my time, and i need to be able to change it to a readable format.  This would need to be in c#.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked intermec?

Comment: absolutely.  They no longer contain that information.

Comment: This looks like it might be useful: http://epsfiles.intermec.com/eps_files/eps_man/961021013A.pdf

Comment: looking at it now, although I want to find someone who has SOME experience with PL\N files

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference guide about 4920/4921 comm controllers with a description of PL/N in appendix B: epsfiles.intermec.com/eps_files/eps_man/961021013A.pdf

I am sorry, but I have NO experience with PL/N.